# import file as module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I wanted to make a cmd tool. I created two files, one named `main.py`, and the other named `version.py`
there are in the same directory

`version.py`:

```py
import os

def pyVersion():
    os.system("python --version")
```

`main.py`:

```py
import version

version.pyVersion()
```

I think it should work, but when I run `main.py`, it prints:

```py
  File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\cmd tool\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'version'
```

Comment: In what directory are you running the code, and is `main.py` in the same directory as `version.py`?

Comment: If version.py and main.py are in the same directory, then there's some other information hidden to us that's the problem. I reproduced this and it worked for me.

Comment: Does your root source directory have a `__init__.py` in it? That is what Python uses to identify a directory with sources it should import. It can be empty.

Comment: Did your repro have an `__init__.py` file in the same directory?

Comment: no, it didn't, i just ran main.py like he did

Comment: The other issue, per Kraigolas's comment, may be that your PYTHONPATH is not properly set. Normally the directory you run it from will be included, but if you're running it from somewhere else you might have an issue.

Comment: code may run from different folder and it may search your modules in different folders. You may have to get path to folder with running code - `BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` - and add it to `sys.path.append(BASE)` before you import `version`

Comment: you can get python version: `print( sys.version_info )`, `print( sys.version )`

Comment: check list `print( sys.path )` to check if `C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\cmd tool\ ` is on this list.

Comment: _there are in the same directory_ Python is looking in the _current directory_ for the module, which is not necessarily the directory where the modules live.

Comment: If everything is in one file it does work?

Answer (score 0):

Normally Python should use folder `C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\cmd tool\`  to search imported modules and you may have this folder even on list `sys.path`

But if it doesn't have this folder on list then you may add it manually before importing module.

```
import sys

# add at the end of list
#sys.path.append(r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\cmd tool\')

# add at the beginning of list
sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\cmd tool\')

import version

# ... code ...
```

To make it more universal you can use `os` to get this folder without hardcoding

```
import os

BASE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
print('BASE:', BASE)

import sys

sys.path.insert(0, BASE)

import version

# ... code ...
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Just import file without the `.py` extension.
2. A folder can be marked as a package, by adding an empty `__init__.py` file.
3. You can use the `__import__` function, which takes the module name (without extension) as a string extension.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site uses [markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to format questions and answers. You should take a look at [formatting help](/help/formatting) for tips on how to use markdown to format your posts nicely.